# How to prove $\forall B\in\Sigma : m(B)<\infty$ and $A\cap B\in\Sigma \Rightarrow A\in\Sigma$ for a $\sigma$-finite $m$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\Sigma,m)$ be a measure space and let $m$ be $\sigma$-finite.  How to prove that $A\subset E$, $\forall B\in\Sigma : m(B)<\infty$ and $A\cap B\in\Sigma \Rightarrow A\in\Sigma$?

How should I even start approaching this? I guess that I somehow have to use the fact that $m$ is $\sigma$-finite meaning that there exists a sequence $E_1,E_2,\ldots\in\Sigma$ so that $\cup_iE_i=E$ and $m(E_i)<\infty\;\forall i$, but I can't see how this can be used for proving the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the measure is sigma finite, then $E=\bigcup_nE_n$ where $m(E_n)<\infty, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $E_n \in \Sigma, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Thus $A=A \cap E=\bigcup_n(E_n \cap A)\in \Sigma$,  since $\Sigma$ is a sigma-algebra.